# Twittertext bug for auto_link_usernames_or_lists when deal with html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

The auto_link_usernames_or_lists can't deal with html well.
when I am trying to generate link using html tag. when you have mention string inside single html element then it not generate link but if you have more than two tag it generate link correctly

```
auto_link_usernames_or_lists('<p>@blankyao</p>')                O/P - No link generated
auto_link_usernames_or_lists('<span><p>@blankyao</p><span>')    O/P - Link generated properly
```

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb/issues/18